# HTTP GET for Netflix

Tags: http, cookies, netflix

I tried to make a GET request for the netflix home page with command prompt because the response returned to me was a 302/301 all the time. So I connected to netflix via the following:

```
telnet signup.netflix.com 80
```

Then the request I made was

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: signup.netflix.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

As copied exactly from LiveHTTPHeaders when I visit netflix however I removed the Cookie part because I don't know where the browser (FireFox) is getting these values

Netflix responds with

[image]

Why don't I get a 200 OK status code? Is it because I'm not sending any cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Its doing a redirect to `https://signup.netflix.com/?tcw=2`. i.e., it wants you to resend the request with the `twc=2` variable in the query string and **more importantly**, with the cookie it just gave you through the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: Edit: how would I do that via cmd?

Comment: Your script will need to parse the returned HTTP response and handle it according to the HTTP specification. You can use any number of HTTP libraries that will automatically do this for you.

Comment: Don't know if this is a stupid question or not but can this be done with php?